# Mule 3.2. How to Evaluate Empty Session Variable in Flow?

Tags: session, groovy, mule, evaluator

How can I check if my session variable is null or empty in this CHOICE
Its not working for me.

```
    <processor-chain doc:name="Processor Chain">
        <choice> 
            <when evaluator="groovy" expression="#[header:session:countryCode] != ">                    
                <logger message="Valid Country Id" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>                 
            </when>            
            <otherwise>
                <logger message="Invalid Country Id" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>                   
            </otherwise>
        </choice>           
    </processor-chain>
```

I also tried != '' and != null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an invalid groovy expression. It should be:

```
    ...
    <when expression="message.getProperty('countryCode',org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.SESSION)!=null 
                      || message.getProperty('countryCode',org.mule.api.transport.PropertyScope.SESSION)!=''"
    evaluator="groovy">
    ...
```

You can also access properties with Header evaluator but I'm not sure if you can evaluate to find out if it is null or empty

Comment: Thanks for your help Daniel but it doesn't solve my problem. If the value is an empty string its not catching it.

Comment: Added the empty string condition in my answer, it should work

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Mule 3.3.x, better use MEL than Groovy:

```
<when expression="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.isNotEmpty(sessionVars.countryCode)]">
```

Comment: If the variable is not empty, but is actually not set, the "." notation will throw an exception.  To handle an unset variable as well, you can use 
    <when expression="#[org.mule.util.StringUtils.isNotEmpty(sessionVars['countryCode'])]">

Comment: True: if there's a risk that the variable may not be present, `sessionVars['countryCode']` is the way to go.